# Nonexistance result of elliptic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I want to prove that there is no $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$-solution of the equation
$−\Delta \phi =\lambda \phi$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that the Pohozaev identity asserts for $N\geq 3$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a non-empty, bounded and open subset with smooth boundary $\delta\Omega$ that if 
 $ \phi \in \mathcal{C}^2(\Omega) \cap \mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)$ is a solution of   $−\Delta \phi =\lambda \phi$ on $Ω$, then
$$∫_Ω2NF(ϕ)−(N−2)ϕf(ϕ)\ dx=∫_{∂Ω}(\frac{∂ϕ}{∂ν})^2(x⋅ν) \ dσ$$

where $F(ϕ)=∫_0^\phi f(τ) dτ=λϕ$ and $f(ϕ)=λϕ$.

I wonder if this is still true for the case $Ω=\mathbb{R}^N$. If it is, then one would have
$$∫_Ω2NF(ϕ)−(N−2)ϕf(ϕ) \ dx=2λ∫_{\Omega = \mathbb{R}^N}ϕ^2(x) dx=0\ \ \ \ \  ∀λ∈R$$
and from this, it follows that $\Vert ϕ\Vert ^2_{L^2}=0$ and so $ϕ=0 $ a.e. on $R^N$, but since $\phi $ is continuous then $\phi = 0$ everywhere on $\mathbb{R} ^N$. Overall, the only $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$-solution of the equation $−Δϕ=λϕ$ is the function zero.

Is my reasoning correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My question is actually why or why not the integral over $\partial\Omega =\partial \mathbb{R}^N$ is zero

Comment: You would have to take the limit of, say $\Omega=B_R(0)$ for $R\to \infty$. However, I don't know how to justify that the right-hand side goes to zero without sufficient a priori knowledge about $\phi$.

Comment: Anyway, the non-existence of $L^2$-solutions is very easy to show using the Fourier transform.

Comment: I have proved it using Fourier. But I want to do it also using Pohozaev identity. I would like to prove, as you Said, that the right hand side integral (over the sphere of radius r) goes to zero as r goes to infinity. I have no idea how to do it formally. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it is because $\phi$ has Compact support so for big enough radius r, $\phi $is zero on the sphere of radius r, and so is also $\partial\phi / \partial \nu$?

Comment: The unique continuation principle (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91436/unique-continuation-principle) tells you that solutions with compact support are zero. My point is: I don't see a method to show that the solution decays fast enough without already showing that it must be zero. If you find one, let us know.

Comment: I just saw that the unique continuation principle is closely related to the Pohozaev identity identity. That's interesting. I fear I can't help, but I would definitively like to know an answer myself. I f you don't get one here, you might also consider asking on mathoverflow.